# Three one dimension or one two dimensional

Tags: c++, c, arrays

In my C and C++ programs, I have three arrays: one for an x coordinate, a y coordinate, and the location in the list. I was wondering if it would take less memory if I put all three in the same array. Any idea? Also, is there something about only having to define one dimension and having the other variable?
Thank you for the help.

Comment: You're mixing terminology. When you say "list", what do you mean?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you using `c` or `c++`? Why are you using arrays and not variables? What do you mean by list?

Comment: The data for the arrays are being taken from a text file in list form. The reason I am using arrays is because there can be upwards of one hundred points to store. I have the program in both c and c++. I like to keep fresh in both languages so I gererally make mirror programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unlikely to take *less* memory to put them together; depending on the structure packing and alignment, it might even take more. That's doubtful in this case though. The most likely outcome is that they'll be the same.

One thing that will be affected is cache coherency. If you usually access all of the values together at the same time, it will be slightly more efficient to have them close together. On the other hand if you typically zip through one array at a time, it will be more efficient to keep them separated.

P.S. If it wasn't obvious, I'm advocating putting the values in a structure rather than a 2D array. The memory layout would be similar but the syntax is different.

Comment: You say "slightly"... I say probably quite a lot, especially seeing as this sounds like graphics.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I haven't really measured lately, so I didn't want to overstate the benefit.

Answer (score 0):

It will take exactly the same amount of memory; it will just be arranged differently.

It is (arguably, generally) better style to have 1 array of complex things, if those things go together.  One reason is you can't accidentally have a different number of each component.

Answer (score 0):

A multi dimenstional array is really just a one dimensional array. With this in mind you would want to use data localization principles (when you access a data point in memory it's easier to load datapoints nearby to it).

Take into consideration whether you'll be accessing your x's in one go then your y's then your locations, or whether you'll be accessing x y and location data all at once.
Look more into how multi -dimensional arrays are represented in memory to decide how you'd "group" your data.